# How remove part of y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse, visualization

I need to output two plots on the same figure, one showing the annual average temperature in celsius, the other in fahrenheit. since the graph is empty within [15;40] to y. I want to remove this part of the graph

```r
library(readr)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

global_temp <- read_csv("X:/global_temp.csv")
View(global_temp)

global_temp$avg_temp_fatenheit <- (9/5 * global_temp['avg_temp'] + 32)
global_temp$avg_temp_fatenheit <- as.numeric(unlist(global_temp$avg_temp_fatenheit))

str(global_temp)

global_temp %>%
  mutate(bin = avg_temp < 15 & avg_temp_fatenheit > 40 ) %>%
  
ggplot() +
  facet_grid(bin ~ ., scale='free_y') +
  geom_line(global_temp, mapping = aes(x = year, y = avg_temp),color = '#6C22A6') +
  geom_point(global_temp, mapping = aes(x = year, y = avg_temp),color = '#6C22A6')+
  geom_line(global_temp, mapping = aes(x = year, y = avg_temp_fatenheit),color = '#96E9C6') +
  geom_point(global_temp, mapping = aes(x = year, y = avg_temp_fatenheit),color = '#96E9C6')+
  labs(title = 'Avarage temperature per year', x = 'Year', y='Temperature (°C - purple) (°F - green)', )+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1750, 2015)) +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10)+
  theme_bw()`
```

I've tried setting limits, but it only works for one graph